# Wodry js animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, animation

Heyy,

On my angular website, I am using the 'wodry js' plugin to create the animated effect as shown in example two from link 1:

http://daynin.github.io/wodry/#examples

https://github.com/daynin/wodry

I have fully installed wodry using bower and grunt and it is working to some extent.

However if I have three words eg. word1, word2, word3

It starts on word1, then spins to show word1word2 together and then spins to show word2word3 etc. instead of showing one word at a time.

This is my code within an HTML doc:

```
<script>

$('.wodry').wodry({
animation: 'rotateX',
delay: 1000,
animationDuration: 800,
});

</script>

<div>
This is a trial run <span class="wodry">word1|word2|word3</span>
</div>
```

How can I correct this please?

Thanks!!